# Set value in Jquery, added a two times the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, setvalue

This is the actual content. While the below code, added a value in dropdown for two times in UI. Shows the dropdown value as "AprilApril" instead of "April"

```
 if ($('#dk_container_selectToYear .dk_options li.dk_option_current a').text() == 2016) {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            var month = currentdate.getMonth();
            var monthname = monthLookup[currentdate.getMonth()];
            month = month + 3;
            while (month <= 13) {
                $('#dk_container_selectToMonth .dk_options li:nth-child(' + month + ')').css({ "display": 'none' });
                var listvalue = $('#dk_container_selectToMonth .dk_options li:nth-child(' + month + ')').text();

                if ($('#dk_container_selectToMonth .dk_options li.dk_option_current a').text() == listvalue) {
                    $('#selectToMonth').dropkick('reset');
                    $('#selectToMonth').dropkick('setValue', monthname);
                }

                month++;
            }
        }


$('#selectToMonth').dropkick('setValue', monthname);
```

Is it have any other option to avoid it..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What does monthLookup look like?

Comment: if you console log `monthname` after you've set it, what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

!!This is not an solution for your question but it is only a hack till you find the solution.
Just grab the half of the string.. like this:

```
var monthname = 'AprilApril';
var month = monthname;
console.log(month.substr(0, (month.length/2))); // April
console.log(month) // AprilApril
```

Enjoy coding!